# Merging time series data so that column values are fitted into dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, time-series

I have two time-series data frames that track the same certain countries throughout the same amount of time, but the variables they track for each observation represent vastly different things. For example, the first data frame is like so:

Tracking variable 'A':

| Country | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | ... | 04/25/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 5000 |
| CHN | 0 | 20 | 50 | ... | 0 |
| USA | 1 | 2 | 4 | ... | 10000 |

The second data frame tracks a different variable 'B' and looks like the following:

| Country | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | ... | 04/25/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 10 | 10 | 0 | ... | 0 |
| CHN | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 20 |
| USA | 0 | 7 | 10 | ... | 543 |

I want to merge these two data frames so that the following is produced ({} to represent internal dictionaries):

| Country | 01/01/2020 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 | ... | 04/25/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | (A: 0, B: 10) | (A: 0, B: 10) | (A: 1, B: 0) | ... | (A: 5000, B: 0) |
| CHN | (A: 0, B: 1) | (A: 20, B: 1) | (A: 50, B: 1) | ... | (A: 0, B: 20) |
| USA | (A: 1, B: 0) | (A: 2, B: 7) | (A: 4, B: 10) | ... | (A: 10000, B: 543) |

Is there a command I am missing in Pandas or is there some type of way to do this I am missing? Thank you for whatever help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Country').agg(list).applymap(
lambda x: dict(zip(['A','B'], [*x]))).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    Country 01/01/2020          01/02/2020  01/03/2020  04/25/2021
0   AFG    {'A': 0, 'B': 10}    {'A': 0, 'B': 10}   {'A': 1, 'B': 0}    {'A': 5000, 'B': 0}
1   CHN    {'A': 0, 'B': 1}     {'A': 20, 'B': 1}   {'A': 50, 'B': 1}   {'A': 0, 'B': 20}
2   USA    {'A': 1, 'B': 0}     {'A': 2, 'B': 7}    {'A': 4, 'B': 10}   {'A': 10000, 'B': 543}
```

**Explanation**

We are first concatenating both dfs using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Then we are grouping the resultant df by country using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

On the grouped df is aggregated using [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to create a list of items based on `Country`.

Then we are mapping the list items to create a `dict` with `A and B` as keys using [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)